# Is it possible to pass the full path of the currently open file in Eclipse to an external tool?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know about the ${selected_resource_loc} but that refers to the selected file in the left navigator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. If you can find the relative path to the file somehow, you can use the `${workspace_loc:<resource path>}` variable expansion to get the absolute file system path.